# Issues with dual-booting High Sierra and Big Sur?

Tags: high-sierra, partition, big-sur, dual-boot, disk-volume

I'm currently dual-booting High Sierra (HS) and Catalina on a 2014 MacBook Pro without issues. HS is my primary OS; I use Catalina for programs that will no longer run on HS (e.g., Turbo Tax).

I'm thinking of upgrading the Catalina partition to Big Sur (BS). The only issue I've found in my reading is that BS must be installed in a separate container (i.e., a separate partition) from HS, not merely a separate volume in the same container.*

My question is:  *Are there any other issues of which I need to be aware?*

*According to this reddit post, installing BS in one volume of a container will cause changes to the container as a whole, and these changes are incompatible with HS. Thus, even though HS and BS both use APFS, they need to be in separate containers.

https://www.reddit.com/r/hackintosh/comments/jun2n2/beware_dont_install_big_sur_in_the_same_apfs/

Here's a post from the Apple forums by a user who installed BS in the same container as HS, and lost access to his HS installation as a result:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252049166

Comment: I disagree with the information found on one of your posted links. I have Mojave and Big Sur installed in the same APFS container on an external Thunderbolt 3 drive and I have no problems updating Mojave. I also have Mojave installed on the internal drive and have no problems updating. Both the internal and external Mojave installations get [this message](https://imgur.com/a/oafoNJD) when logging in. In my case, I do not see what is to be gained by using separate APFS containers.

Comment: @DavidAnderson   Could there be an issue specific to having HS and BS in the same container, that doesn't apply to BS + Mojave or Catalina?  Do you know of any examples of successful HS/BS dual-boots from the same container?  In my searching thus far, I've not yet found any.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if there is no problem of disk space, it's better separate containers of different System in APFS structure.

The other thing to separate well is the data according to the systems used. Indeed, the compatibility of "integrated Apple" software is always upward but rarely downward. Thus if data used by "High Sierra" version software is used by the same "Big Sur" version software, there is little chance that the powerful "High Sierra" software will then have access to it.